# Drupal View with Grid option problems in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I recently created a drupal view for a image gallery (clickable thumbnails) from a set of files. This is a 'view' Format:Grid with 3 columns. I loaded in File:Path, Caption, & Title and accomplished the view by "Rewriting Results" from "File:Title" using the following:

```
<div style="width:200px;"><td width="200px" ><a href="[uri]" style="max-width: 200px;">[field_title]<img src="[uri]" alt="ITSO" width="200px" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px;" />[field_caption]</a></td></div>
```

So this works great in Chrome and Safari, however my downfall is Firefox. I've tried to define width with -moz but Firefox ignores EVERYTHING I put in. It displays the title, an image so large it goes off the window and caption, no resizing at all. My latest try was to use border-box but no luck, the following showed no changes.

```
<div style="width:200px; max-width: 200px; -webkit-column-width: 200px; -moz-column-width: 200px; column-width: 200px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; float: left;"><td width="200px" > <a href="[uri]" style="text-decoration:none; max-width: 200px;">[field_title]<img src="[uri]" alt="ITSO" width="200px" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px;" />[field_caption]</a></td></div>
```

When I change it to a % instead of px definition I get resizing in Chrome of image and column width but no change in Firefox.

```
<div style="width:20%; max-width: 20%; -webkit-column-width: 20%; -moz-column-width: 20%; column-width: 20%; -moz-box-sizing: 20%; display: inline-block; float: left;"><td width="20%" > <a href="[uri]" style="text-decoration:none; max-width: 20%;">[field_title]<img src="[uri]" alt="ITSO" width="20%" style="width: 20%; max-width: 20%;" />[field_caption]</a></td></div>
```

I also noticed that when I specify "text-decoration:none" it is ignored by both Chrome & Firefox. Isn't inline supposed to overrule? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I don't have full drupal permissions so I'm not allowed to add classes or access administrator drupal areas, so I'd love to find a way just to tell all browsers to use the same width on my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Firefox is the problem. ALL style width commands are straight up ignored. The way to do this & use Views Format: Grid is to rewrite the output with:

```
<div class="craxypic"><a href="[uri]">[field_title]<img src="[uri]"  />[field_caption]</a></div>
```

Then you have to put class craxypic in your css file with:

```
.craxypic {
<td width="200px" > 
width: 200px;
-webkit-column-width: 200px;
-moz-column-width: 200px;
column-width: 200px;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
text-decoration:none;
max-width: 200px;
</td>}
```

This is the only way to get all the browsers to acknowledge your width command. I am still learning drupal, and I have to say at this point it is reminding me alot of iraf. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: In an interesting side-note, the solution will look terrible in preview mode, but perfect on the final page.

Answer (score 0):

can you try and avoid using the TD tag in the first place, I'm not sure that unless you wrap it in a table the TD will  work.
Also, if you can edit some CSS try and avoid using the grid and use unordered list instead and display:inline-block; on the LI elements, or flexbox even better
That would allow you to print all the fields without all that HTML into the rewrite function of a single field. It would make a cleaner faster and responsive code.

Comment: size should be placed in the CSS file, not inline printed from a rewrite field
have you got a live url to check the output of the grid ?

Comment: If I don't use the TD tag I get the same problem in Firefox with an additional issue that in Chrome the columns are uneven. The unordered list & slideshow both fill the page but do not go over the page as in the case of the grid option. However, the idea is to create at least 2 or 3 columns with an image gallery type effect so I'd like to find a way to make the grid view work. Especially as it 'does' appear correctly in Chrome, just not Firefox. I could make an image block and css write my own clickable images into an set of divs, but that would be harder to update and much less user friendly.

Comment: Just to clarify, all my comments about the size being incorrect in the browser Firefox is the size of the image on the live site. The "Views" preview window looks correct with just a basic rewrite of output statement.

Comment: Create an image style for images to be scaled and cropped to 200pxX200px
Edit your view to print the fields Title (no-rewrite), Image and Caption
Set the image to style you just created and link the image to the original content.
Set the view display=grid, 3 columns, 
Is not going to be nice on mobile but it seems to me that is not a priority

Best practice, though, if you can edit CSS, make the view display as UL and use flexbox
https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Comment: Just read your clarification, it seems to me then that it might be a overriding CSS from the default theme.